# Using OAuth in Yahoo! API Requests (Python)

Tags: python, oauth, yahoo-api

I'm trying to integrate an application with a Yahoo! api that requires oauth authentication to access protected data.

I'm using [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) and following along with the steps listed in Yahoo's [Oauth Authorization Flow](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html) document. I've been able to complete all of the steps to negotiate an access token with Yahoo, but do not seem to be able to use the [token to authenticate](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html).

Here is my code:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

def list_users(token):
    # token is the access token i save in the DB
    oauth_token = oauth.Token(token.token, token.secret)
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=settings.OATH_CONSUMER_KEY, 
                              secret=settings.OATH_SECRET)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, oauth_token)
    resp, content = client.request((LIST_USERS_URL), "GET")
    return content
```

However, all I'm able to get back is an error message that says "Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="signature_invalid", realm="yahooapis.com""

What am I doing wrong here? Everything else worked smoothly up to this point.

Comment: Have you run though the `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token` procedure before calling `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?` and finally heading to `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token` for the actual access_token? One common issue is to mix-up request_token as access_token.

Comment: Yep, I'm getting the request token and the access token and using the access token to authenticate.

Comment: If access_token is ok, the only little error is a missing "(" in `resp, content = client.request(LIST_USERS_URL), "GET")`. The last thing to check is [application scopes](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-scopes.html), is it correct during registration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel a bit sheepish. So it turns out that Yahoo also throws this exact error when you access an invalid API call. So in my case I was accessing a root API when I had to specify a sub API. Moral of the story: beware that oauth errors might be representative of other issues in your app/code.