# Authorizing Yahoo requests after OAuth successful

Tags: ios, oauth, yahoo-api

I got Yahoo OAuth 1 authorization working, now I'm trying to add Authorization headers to social API requests.

I'm getting 401 / OST_OAUTH_SIGNATURE_INVALID_ERROR and I suspect its because of how I'm generating the signature base string. I'm using the same code that's working for the OAuth `get_request_token`/`get_token`, leading me to think my base string encoding and signature generation is correct (its based on AFNetworking AFOAuth1Client for iOS).

If anyone has this working, can you please post an example like the Yahoo's documentation page https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-make-request.html, except also showing the construction of the signature base string?

Here's a log of my successful acquire of OAuth1 access credentials, followed by my unsuccessful social.yahooapis.com request https://gist.github.com/jpmhouston/680ba3a3c09039c66230

Can anyone see what's wrong the construction of that request's Authorization header? Or anything else wrong with that request?

(The answer to this similar question makes me wary, [Using OAuth in Yahoo! API Requests (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205534/using-oauth-in-yahoo-api-requests-python), essentially saying "signature_invalid" errors can result from mistakes other than authentication!)

Comment: Check to make sure the API you are calling (social) supports OAuth 1.0.  In the documentation it mentions OAuth 2.0 is supported but I did not see OAuth 1.0. From the yahoo OAuth 2 guide: OAuth 2.0 is currently supported by Yahoo Gemini and Yahoo Social APIs.

Comment: A yahoo.com I was looking at last month said OAuth 2 was only support by one of Yahoo's services, probably something about ads (is that what Gemini is?). This could have been old content though. So thanks, I'll into that further. But assuming they haven't ditched OAuth 1 for social, something I think would have been more prominent in their documentation and forums, my question still stands.